# react.js the above error occurred in the <div> component (there is no error above)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am trying to get a React App up and going. I copied in some HTML from a template into a component. I am running into an error and its not really clear how to handle it. Here is the error. Note **there is no error above**:

```
'index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the <div> component:
    in div (at App.js:57)
    in div (at App.js:28)
    in div (at App.js:15)
    in div (at App.js:14)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

Here is the code that I am placing in App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Test from './components/Test.js'
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
render() {
return (

<React.Fragment>
  <Test />

<div className="probootstrap-hero">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center probootstrap-hero-text pb0 probootstrap-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
        <h1>Launch your awesome startup now!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto provident qui tempore natus quos quibusdam soluta at.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Get This App</a>
          <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary btn-ghost btn-lg" role="button">Try it for free</a>
        </p>
        <p><a href="#"><i className="icon-play2"></i> Watch the video</a></p> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   
   </React.Fragment>
)}
```

Comment: Have you closed the fragment? `</React.Fragment>`

Comment: div's are not balanced

Comment: Yes. I closed the fragment. Just did not include it. Sorry

Comment: need 2 more `</div>` and `</React.Fragment>`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt want to copy all the code. The divs are balanced and the react.fragment is closed properly. I have eslint installed, so I know that all the divs are balanced, I have no errors coming from eslint right now. The code, seemingly, should work.

Comment: When it says "the above error occured" that refers to an error which occured. It's more useful if we had that error as well.

Comment: Hence the problem. There is no error above that

Comment: Did you intend for `class` to be capitalized?

Comment: The code works fine without the <Test /> component, maybe that's where the error is. Be aware that you are missing a `}` at the end as well.

Answer (score 42):

This happens when you use style as a string instead of an object - among less common other reasons like using an object as style and throwing an error in its toString method.

But here is the most reason that such an error is thrown

```
// the following is JSX and not html
<div style="color:red" />
```

Comment: I also had this putting a `<button>` inside an `<input>` (yes the input was being opened and closed, but I think it's a spec violation)

Comment: @mikemaccana yea it's a spec violation, though browser engines will know how to handle it. But its good that react is crashing on this :)

Comment: Wow, that's some bad error reporting :(

Comment: If you want to use inline style, you have to do it like that: `<div style={{color: "red"}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by something like `<div style="position: absolute" />`. I am also aware this is wrong, but I really think that react should report a proper error for this to give you a hint why the application is crashing).

> `<div style="position: absolute" />` 
> // the following is JSX and not html

Style use in `className=''` and

Use this

> `<div className='position: absolute'`